# Toggle switch is not working properly in react native flat list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a flat list that renders using the data from the redux state. Data is an array of objects in which I have a boolean value based on that I'm rendering a toggle switch.

The data from the redux is huge and currently does not have any pagination enabled. The problem is **while I'm trying to update the switch value it's going to a false state and returns to true immediately and vice versa**.

I can't update the redux state each time for switch values as the data is huge and will take time to re-render. Is there any way to keep the switch enable/disable without actually depending on the redux data.

**code:**

```
<FlatList
  data={this.props.data}
  renderItem={this.renderlist}
  keyExtractor={item => item.id}
  maxToRenderPerBatch={10}
  initialNumToRender={5}
  updateCellsBatchingPeriod={1}
  windowSize={7}
/>
```

Render function

```
const renderlist = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      <Switch
        value={item.status ? true : false}
        onValueChange={(val) => {
          this.editData(item, val);
        }}
        color={COLORS.primary}
        style={styles.switch}
      />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Even though you may be using redux, you still have component state available to you. If the toggle is something local to a particular component, why not consider using the traditional `this.state`? If you need it across the entire app, a dispatch on `componentWillUnmount()` should suffice when you go to the next component.